# How to get FTP upload percentage with Laravel File System

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, ftp, filesystems

So I have application like `wetransfer.com`.

So i want to see how many of the file bytes are uploaded to the `ftp` disk

Here is a example code:

`Storage::disk('ftp')->put('/path/', $file)`

Scheme:

`(client file) -> (ftp)`

Is there any way to get the upload percentages of the server and how many bytes are uploaded to the `FTP`.

I use React for the front end side. Here is my code

```
  const onDrop = useCallback(acceptedFiles => {
        setShowUpload(false);
        const uploading = acceptedFiles.map(file => {
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("cloudesk_upload[]", file);
            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.upload.onprogress = event => {
                const percentage = parseInt((event.loaded / event.total) * 100);
                setUploadPercentages(percentage);
            };
            xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
                if (xhr.readyState !== 4) return;
                if (xhr.status !== 200) {
                    console.log('error'); // Handle error here
                }
                console.log('success'); // Handle success here
            };

            setTimeout(() => {
                xhr.open('POST', `${window.API_URL}/upload`, true);
                xhr.send(formData);
            }, 3000)
        });
    }, [])
```

But that not work as i expected

The way i think this can be done is:

`(client) -> (temp file on the first server) -> (ftp)`
and then get the bytes between the Local file and Ftp file.

Is there any simple no dirty way to do that?

Comment: you want to get that percent on server or on client side. If you want to get percentage on client side have you used ajax to upload the file or just form post?

Comment: I want to get the percentage on server side

Comment: @DeepeshThapa I updated my question, see it!

Comment: Does your question mean that you want to show the upload progress bar and want to get upload progress percentage to be displayed on your website? Or did you mean you want to get the total files that had been uploaded to the server?

Comment: I want to get upload progress percentages and displayed it on my website @DeepeshThapa

Comment: Thanks. I dont know the react way but i know how it works with jquery ajax.

Comment: @DeepeshThapa Give me Jquery/Ajax some example please, i will implement it in react by myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After understanding your problem you can compare the file size between your uploaded file and file you stored in your ftp server.

This function is for demo purpose.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $file= Input::file('file');
  $clientFileSize=$request->file('file')->getSize();
  Storage::disk('ftp')->put('/path/', $file);
  $ftpFileSize=Storage::disk('ftp')->size('/path/filename');
  $comparesize=$clientFileSize-$ftpFileSize
  
}
```

Comment: Yeah, its just show the form upload percentage not the ftp

Comment: I am still soo confused. What is your exact question?

Comment: Did you mean you want to show the bytes of the file being uploaded rather than percentage?

Comment: I just want to get the original file size from the file and compare it on the ftp server file

Comment: Ohh so, from my understanding. You want to compare between the original file size you uploaded and file size stored in ftp?